# What is this sword that Gandalf's horse was carrying?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, weapon, object-identification

[image]

When Gandalf arrives in Isengard, and takes off his hat to greet Saruman, there is a sword attached to the saddle of his horse, as highlighted in the picture. What is this sword? I don't think it's Glamdring.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Glamdring, Foe Hammer

This is indeed one of the variations of Glamdring made by Weta Workshop, the prop designers for both the Lord of the Rings and The Hobbit film series.

From [this link](http://wetaworkshop.com/projects/the-lord-of-the-rings-fotr/) on their site. You can see the sword in the top right of the image but I've also provided as screenshot here:

[image: Glamdring from Weta] [image: Glamdring from video]

If you look at the two photos you'll see the two hilts are indeed the same.

I've touched up the photo a bit. You can now clearly see the crosses on the grip as well as below down the top of the scabbard. The guard is also clearly the same.

Comment: Yeah and I don't think tha'ts Glamdring

Comment: Hm. Scratch that, I think they're the same. The shot OP provided doesn't have that blob on the top, but I just rewatched that scene, and they look the same.

Comment: Do you mean the pommel?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Look at Mr. Fancy bringing out all his sword knowledge! (Thanks for the edits :-D )

Comment: I've been put into contact with the artist at Weta and will hopefully have evidence soon

Comment: you can think the sky is purple and full of unicorns - that doesn't make it so @anakindchosenone05192005 - that is clearly the same sword

Comment: If that's Galmdring, then how did he reclaim it again later during the battle at moria